# WDDM 1.1 for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone-7

I am trying to install WDDM 1.1 for windows 7.

But I could not get any link which gives the installer. I installed Nvidia, but I t installs WDDM 1.0.

Please give a link which installs WDDM 1.1.

Comment: I have the same issue using NVIDIA GeForce Go 7300. Even drivers from guru3d.com provide only WDDM 1.0

Comment: @Mikhail: I just updated my answer with some modded drivers that might work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of modded Windows 7 drivers that may work for you. Read the readme thoroughly so you understand how to install them.

#### Installing the driver:

> 1. Download driver, double click and select extract,
> 2. Download modded INF and replace original INF in extracted folder,
> 3. Install & reboot.

[Readme](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/9243-forceware-updaters-quickstart-guide/)
[32 bit version - 263.09](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27593-v26309-windows-7vista-32bit-nvidia-desktop/page__p__134247)
[64 bit version - 263.09](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27594-v26309-windows-7vista-64bit-nvidia-desktop/page__p__134248)

[Main Download Site](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/drivers)

Comment: That's the point of the question. Is there any work around? To run apps on WP7 emulator we need WDDM 1.1. Can anything be done other than buying a new video card? I'm using a laptop, so I'd really like a solution.

Comment: I think the problem comes in 2 steps. 1) installing newer driver. 2) having the driver install WDDM 1.1. You've showed me how to solve the first problem. But for the second one, i'm starting to believe that I'm SOL

Comment: This guy says that drivers 185.81 install WDDM 1.1 (http://i239.photobucket.com/albums/ff305/kpo6969/18581.jpg) however when I install it I get 1.0 (http://i56.tinypic.com/1julv9.png)... what the hell?

Comment: I think you're out of luck in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

It's correct you need a WDDM1.1 compliant driver to run the WP7 emulator to it's full capacity.

You can try updating your display driver through windows or from your display adapter manufacturer's site.

Sometimes there just isn't a WDDM1.1 driver available though for some adapters. In this case your only option is to upgrade your display adapter to one which does come with a WDDM1.1 compliant driver.